# Double files in "Local changes" window

Tags: intellij-idea

My IntelliJ Idea shows me double files in "Local changes" window.

I opened *workspace.xml* file and in fact, entries are doubled like this:

```
<change afterPath="$PROJECT_DIR$/ws/MyFile.scala" afterDir="false" />
<change afterPath="$USER_HOME$/someDirectory/ws/MyFile.scala" afterDir="false" />
```

Two entries, two different paths, the same File!
How can I fix that?

Comment: Any symlinks in the project?

Comment: @CrazyCoder No.

Comment: What directories are associated with the version control in the IDE Settings?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Bingo! Two roots were registered there! I dont know why, but after removing one root, the problem seems to be fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that only one directory is associated with the version control at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control in the IDE.